# Making a lineRenderer component move in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to have this line here [image] move along an axis each time I click it. This component is being generated with lineRenderer.

Extra: I need the line to move to the opposite side of where I clicked.

Can anyone help?

Best,
IC

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example achieving the basis of what you want (Clicking the line and repositioning), however it requires a 3D collider so add that to the GameObject, resize it appropriately, **make sure to turn off Use World Space in the line renderer component**, and then add this script.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveLine : MonoBehaviour {

private LineRenderer line;
private Camera thisCamera;
private Ray ray;
private RaycastHit hit;

void Awake () {
    line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    thisCamera = FindObjectOfType<Camera>().GetComponent<Camera>();
}

public void OnMouseDown () {
    Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
    ray = thisCamera.ScreenPointToRay(mousePos);

    if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
    {
        print (hit.collider.name);
        line.transform.position = new Vector3(5, 5, 5); //Change to whatever position you need
    }
}
}
```

## UPDATE

OK, the functionality you want can be achieved several different ways. Here's how I would do it with minimal code changes to the script above:

Firstly remove the box colliders and 'MoveLine' script from your linerenderer gameobject, then add two empty child objects to it. Call one LeftSide and the other RightSide. Add one 3D boxcollider to each of these child objects (sides) and, as you may have guessed, the right box collider should be positioned so it covers the right side of the renderer and the left on the left side of the renderer (try not to let them overlap, but get as close as possible).

Now rename your MoveLine script to MoveLineLeft, duplicate it and rename the other to MoveLineRight. **Do not forget to change the class names as well**. Add 'MoveLineRight' to the 'LeftSide' gameobject (as you said you wanted a click on the left to move it to the right) and add 'MoveLineLeft' to the 'RightSide' gameobject.

Open both scripts; in 'MoveLineLeft' on the line where it says line.transform.position...etc. remove and add this instead:

```
line.transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x - 1, 0, 0);
```

in 'MoveLineRight' on the same line remove it again and add the following:

```
line.transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + 1, 0, 0);
```

**Extra Update**
Also change GetComponent to GetComponentInParent in the Awake function in both scripts to make sure your objects know where to get the line renderer from.

This should now give you the effect you want. When you Click on the left side of the line it'll move right and vice-versa. Now if you want to change direction when you click to something different than + / - 1, simply change the values of the two lines, or create a public variable so you can do it whilst in the inspector. Hope this has helped!

Comment: Thank you JonHerbert for your kind reply :)

I've followed your indications and added the code, a box collider 2D and made sure the Use World Space was disabled (it was already). Still doesn't work though. Screenshot: https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/540c820050e7d44326ca09ee/1842x920/889c62fb5f690ad2cae41bdfec1817b7/upload_25_5_2015_at_12_40_40.png.

I was thinking maybe I need to generated 2 box colliders, each to the side of the line, so when I would click either of them, the line could move? What do you think? Sorry I'm a newbie programmer :/

Comment: No problem!  I should have been a little clearer, this was with a 3D box collider, not a 2D one. Have you tried that? Or will this cause problems for your project?

Comment: Ahhh! Ok. I now understand. Well, the thing is: right now when we click within the box collider, it will simply jump to the position 5,5,5 that was defined in the script. What we need, it to be able to click on the left side of the line (or the right side) and have the line move itself 1 unit to the opposite direction. Imagine the line has to "run away from the click" :)

Comment: Check the Update on my answer and follow very carefully from there. I have it working as I describe, and i think this is what you are after.

Comment: Hey! Just tried out your solution and I get a error: http://tinyurl.com/oh8rkuw. I guess the getComponent is trying to grab the LineRenderer as if it was in the child object itself instead of the parent one. Also, a small side question related to this method: I have the player spawning dynamically each time I run the game (i.e. he could spawn either on the left side, or the right side). What would be the easiest way to have one of these child objects spawn along with it (and correctly-sided), so that each player has his own area (through the server? Here's the spawn: http://tinyurl.com/pdrwb4e

Comment: You've figured out the solution for yourself, as you say it needs to find it in the parent object, so add the GetComponentInParent instead of just GetComponent in the Awake function. As for the second question I would make another question and ask, I have little to no server knowledge myself. In short you should look up 'Instantiate' in the documents and see if you can find a solution there. Along with Random.Range to help decide where they should spawn randomly.

Comment: Thank you again for all your kind replies :) So, I fixed the parent search and the lines do move. But there's a weird thing going on: we're incrementing the X axis position by 1 and yet, it moves some other value (it seems to depend on the size of the BoxCollider itself). Right now I have it like this http://tinyurl.com/o8kru89. So, with this 50 size setting, it is right now moving 24 units instead of 1... The situation after the first click: http://tinyurl.com/otjv4b8. Previously X was 0. Are we incrementing this correctly?

Comment: The problem is this: You are moving the transform of the object -25 in the x position, rather than the boxcollider in the x position. The solution: make sure the leftside and rightside objects have 0 in the x position in the transform. Then in the box collider put 25 (rightside) and -25(leftside) in the 'Center' x position, thus moving only the box collider and not the gameobjects themselves